# System.InvalidOperationException when try to add new row on DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I've added some columns to a DataGridView using `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and `DataGridViewColumn`

```
 Public Function a(ByVal wellName As String) As DataGridView
        ' Grid creation
        Dim grid As DataGridView = New DataGridView With {
            .Width = 1250,
            .DataSource = New DataTable(),
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
            }

        ' Filling operations
        grid.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewColumn With {
            .HeaderText = "ID",
            .Name = "ID",
            .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
        })

    Dim literatureDGVCB = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell() 'We don't know the lithology
        literatureDGVCB.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        literatureDGVCB.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat

        grid.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn With {
            .HeaderText = "Literature",
            .Name = "literature",
            .CellTemplate = literatureDGVCB,
            .DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing,
            .[ReadOnly] = True
        })

    [ . . . ]

    Return grid
End Function
```

Now, when i try to call

```
grid.Rows.Add( something )
```

i obtain a `System.InvalidOperationException`: "Cannot add rows programmatically to the DataGridView row collection if associated with control data." (or something like that: I'm translating).

How can I solve it?

Comment: Remove the `.DataSource = New DataTable(),` part. Either the DataGridView has a DataSource (in which case, you add rows to the source, not the DGV) or it doesn't (in which case, you add rows to the DGV itself). It appears that what you're trying to do is the latter.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Where is the data in the grid coming from and going to? Particularly if it is from a database but maybe even if it isn't, you actually should be binding to a `DataTable`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i've filled the grid by `.Value` modification. Ahmed solution works perfectly!

Comment: That is not an answer to my question.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry! I didn't understand the question, then... _"Where is the data coming?"_ From the lines `x.value = val`. _"...And going to?"_ Nowhere: they are displayed in the datagridview and that's it

Comment: I don't think the site will let me add a facepalm emoji. I didn't ask you what code you were using to put data into cells. I asked you where the data is coming from. Is it a database? A file? User input? Some other source? If you have a combo box column then you must have items in the drop-down list so that data at least must have come from somewhere. Also, it seems rather odd that you would have a grid in which the user selects items from a drop-down list and then you do absolutely nothing with the selections they make.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Forgive me, but if I couldn't insert a row after creating the table (before Ahmed's suggestion, As can be seen in the posted code) what data could I have entered?
I had only tested a direct entry, specifying the values ​​from the code!
In any case, I think that you did not understand the problem, since it was related to creating an empty row and not inserting data... Anyway, I repeat, Ahmed's suggestion solved it perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Ahmed Abdelhameed, removing the line `DataSource = New DataTable(),` the problem is solved.